# Can't recreate mysql user

Tags: mysql, database

I am using mysql-server 5.5.41-0+wheezy1 on Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64

I have problems (not related to mysql) on some on my web app that uses mysql table so I am doing a re-install of the app

I started with `aptitude remove packagename` to remove my app and mysql-server, but it seems that it did not remove/delete the currently used mysql databases

When I reinstall mysql-server the previous database still used. I drop the previous user to create a new one using the command `drop user olduser` and also I drop the old database `drop database olddb`

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

Now when I recreate the database with new name, it is a sucess, but if I recreate the same old user `create user 'olduser'@'localhost' identified by 'somesecret';` it will always say `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'olduser'@'localhost'` Creating a different user is a success, but this problem of recreating the same old user is bugging me. Is there something wrong or something I missed?

I have tried `flush privileges`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's kinda hard to debug this without having any access to the database, this error is common with MySQL, but normally a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` fix it. Anyway, if really the user is dropped you can bypass it that way :

```
CREATE USER 'anyuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test123';
UPDATE mysql.user SET USER='olduser' WHERE USER='anyuser';
```

Note that to completly remove an user, you must delete all datas associated to it in these tables : `columns_priv`, `db`, `procs_priv`, `tables_priv`. Then finally execute flush privileges.

From the doc :

> DROP USER does not automatically drop or invalidate databases or
>   objects within them that the old user created. This includes stored
>   programs or views for which the DEFINER attribute names the dropped
>   user. Attempts to access such objects may produce an error if they
>   execute in definer security context. (For information about security
>   context, see Section 18.5, “Access Control for Stored Programs and
>   Views”.)

Comment: I will try to see those tables if there is still olduser references in it. Thanks

Comment: I am going to high five you to the moon @Jean-François Savard . There is still a record left on `mysql.db`. Deleting that record allowed me to recreate the olduser. Why is `drop user` did not do that automagically? Using GUI mysql manager seems more easy.

Comment: @skeith see edit pasted from the documentation, drop user does not remove all references properly.